# TYPO3 TCA pages types add Tab

Tags: typo3

I want to add an existing tab to special pagetype.
For example tab "social media" to pagetype 254 (folder).
So i used mergeRecursiveWithOverrule like this, but then i redefine all.
Can i only add a single tab?

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ArrayUtility::mergeRecursiveWithOverrule(
    $GLOBALS['TCA']['pages'],
    [
        'types' => [
            254 => [
                'showitem' => '
                    --div--;LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/Form/locallang_tabs.xlf:general, --palette--;;standard, --palette--;;titleonly, ,
                    --div--;LLL:EXT:seo/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.tabs.socialmedia, --palette--;;opengraph, --palette--;;twittercards,
,...
,
'
            ]
        ],
    ],
);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`ExtensionManagementUtility::addToAllTCAtypes()` is what you are looking for, especially the third parameter.

Parameters of `addToAllTCAtypes()`:

1. Name of the table to which the fields should be added.
2. Comma-separated string of fields, the same syntax used in the showitem property of types in TCA.
3. Optional: record types of the table where the fields should be
   added,    see types in TCA for details.
4. Optional: position ('before' or 'after') in relation to an existing
   field.

Docs: [Extension Development -> Extending the TCA array -> Customization Examples](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/ExtendingTca/Examples/Index.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot, so for example third parameter means for table pages doktype_shortcut and doktype_sysfolder '4,254'? I had only tt_content with different types in my mind.

Comment: Yes, exactly. `type` can be configured for each table (https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/main/en-us/Ctrl/Properties/Type.html). The well knows ones are `pages.doktype` and `tt_content.CType`, but also e.g. `be_users.admin` is a type-column and switches between admin-/non-admin BE users.